# How to format json string in batch script

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, curl

I'm new in windows scripting.

I got multiple vars and I'm looking to create a JSON object in batch script in order to perform a POST request using curl.

How can I do that?

Is there any windows function like `"{ name: {0} }".format("James")`?

Comment: `set "name=James"` then `curl args "{ name: '%name%' }"` is the closest equivalent to `.format("James")'` plugged into `{0}` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @rojo it works, thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to [Rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo)

I just had to add quotes on vars as:

`curl -d "{ \"first\": \"%first_name%\", "\last\": \"%last_name%\"}"`